# Regex to remove relative path from the url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, url

I have a use case, where any format of relative can happen.
Like:

```js
const URL1 = "./hello-world"
const URL2 = "../hello-world"
const URL3 = "../../hello-world"
const URL4 = "../../../hello-world"
const URL5 = "../../../../hello-world"
```

So on and so forth.
All I care about is the actual absolute path which means:

**`output: hello-world`**

Which Regex or functions (preferably in JS) could I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = "../../../../hello-world";
const output = input.replace(/\.+\//g, '');
console.log(output); // hello-world
```

What it does is to find '.' chain which ends with the '/'. It will match every chain of dots which ends with slash.